# Do we really need all of these closure-related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonymization

We have a LOT of tags that are basically about closure.  Can we synonymize some of those?

[close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons), [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions), [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close), and [closing-questions](/questions/tagged/closing-questions) can't all be sufficiently independent, can they?  I do see that except for [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) they are all pretty close in terms of usage rates...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are all distinct topics and should not by synonymised.

- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) is for discussing our canonical and custom close **reasons**.
- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) is for raising meta discussions about specific closed **questions**, and the concept of a closed question in general.
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) is about a type of **vote** and its related privileges.
- [closing-questions](/questions/tagged/closing-questions) is about discussions about the closing **process** itself.

Closes (and holds) are an important part of how the site functions and has many moving parts. These tags are natural categories that arose to label some of the distinct moving parts of this critical site feature.

Comment: Oh, ok. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: tag wiki and excerpts added.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Oh, thank you! Meta tag wikis tend to get neglected.